# What is the purpose of the formatting sandbox?

Tags: discussion, meta, sandbox

I went from the Community user to the Sandbox archive to the Formatting Sandbox.
 What is the point of any of these?
I read the formatting sandbox description but you can see how your text will be formatted when you write a question. I only see it being useful to test bugs with the editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term "sandbox" has meaning in software development, as can be seen on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)):

> A sandbox is a testing environment that isolates untested code changes and outright experimentation from the production environment or repository

In essence, here on Mata Stack Exchange and any meta site having its own sandbox, it means users can just experiment in the sandbox without hijacking existing questions.

This can be used to experiment with:

- Answers
- Comments
- Edits
- Rollbacks
- Formatting of any kind
- Things that might break design/usability of the site
- Rate limits
- ...and more.

While there are no rules set in stone, those are my own personal guidelines:

1. You don't have to delete your answer when you're done testing, but please limit yourself to single answer. If you need more, delete them afterwards to not clutter the sandbox.
2. Comment as you wish on your own answer, but when commenting on other answers or the question just to test stuff, please delete the comment(s) when done.
3. If the answer breaks design/usability really badly, please delete when done, or remove the offending part, leaving a comment or explanation.

That's about it, happy sandboxing!

Comment: Is there a similar way to then experiment with questions?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 no.

Answer (score 3):

The formatting sandbox is a playground for markdown.

It is a place for people to try different things with markdown on the site without fear of downvotes.

Comment: Could low-scored answers in the formatting sandbox count towards an answer-ban?

Comment: What is markdown?

Comment: @JohnMiliter - probably. We don't distinguish that post from any others.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown - I am surprised you need people to find such things for you. It is a fairly unique term to search for and find relevant results for.

Comment: @Oded - I was looking for a more descriptive answer. Yours did not make anything clearer to me. See Shadow Wizard's. And considering that you can probably get an answer-ban then how do downvotes not matter?

Comment: @Akaisteph7: Post-bans on Meta are quite rare, as the algorithm is detuned to make it much less sensitive. Unless you go really crazy with lots and lots of downvoted sandbox posts, it won't make a real difference.